# Incorrect TOC even though paragraph styles are correct: why?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I have the following Word 2007 document that I have built up containing personal notes.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=15bASxtOf0pm6OWtJXeoszIG3iTgEKZcN

It is stripped down massively just to demonstrate this problem.  The table of contents (I need this to have 6 levels) just will not generate correctly.

You can see it contains entries which when clicked are clearly formatted with the normal style.

I can get around this by manually changing the styles of the erroneous entries to "Normal" but in the document proper there are far too many to do this procedure for all of them.

Can anyone tell me what has happened and how to automatically repair this please?

PS: I have searched several times for someone with the same problem, perhaps I've used the wrong search terms, but please don't downvote assuming I have not put due diligence in before asking here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downloaded and dug through your document.  The issue is that the Normal style or Code style that is appearing in your TOC has been assigned an Outline level.  For example, some of the green Error text ("Code" style) is assigned "Level 1" rather than "Body text."

Use the Style Inspector and Reveal Formatting to show all the information about any text in your document.  Refer to the images linked below.

Also, you should create discrete styles for each unique type of formatting contained in your document.  Then, you can assign shortcut keys to the styles to quickly apply them.

If you use the Normal style for everything (but headings) and you change the Normal style, it will result in changing all the text formatted using the Normal style and removing any other applied attributes (e.g. shading or green font).

[image: Displaying the list of styles in your document]
[image: Display Style Inspector pane]
[image: Change Outline Level to "Body text"]

Comment: Thank you very much; I have followed your excellent diagrams and see exactly what you mean.  Do you possibly know how I could update all of these problematic areas and change their outline level to "body" instead of "Level 1"?  The document proper is huge and I cannot really change everything to normal style then reapply all the formatting/shading that is necessary...

Comment: You can use the Navigation Pane to identify any parts of your document formatted with an Outline level other than body text.  You'll see the Navigation Pane displayed in the images I already posted.  Unless you create unique styles for all of your formatted text, you'll remove any formatting applied to text with the "Normal" style applied.  My suggestion is to create the unique styles you need, then assign them shortcut keys.  This will allow you to go through the document pretty quickly to apply your styles where appropriate.  Please upvote my answer if it helps you solve the problem.